# JQuery slide effects on drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I created jquery dropdown menu like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq9Ky/). I want to add slide effect on drop down menu. At the same time if I am placing my mouse over my menu tab the sub menu was opened now it is looking like one step up compare to the menu tab. I need slide like  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3aK9k/4/). I here added my script.

```
function mainmenu() {
    jQuery(" #na1").hover(function () {
//alert("hai-2");
        jQuery(this).find('#content1').slideDown("fast");
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).find('#content1').slideUp("fast");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    mainmenu();
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you be more clear about what you are expecting ?

Comment: I think this site provides the solution: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#na ul li").hover(function () {
         $(this).siblings().find('ul').slideUp(400);
         $(this).find('ul').slideDown(400);        
    }, function () {
       $(this).find('ul').slideUp(400);
    });
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/QkbDg/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#na ul li a").hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).next('ul').slideDown(350);
    }, function () {
        jQuery(this).next('ul').slideUp(350);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq9Ky/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mainmenu(){
    jQuery(" #na1").hover(function(){
        jQuery(this).find('#content1').stop().slideDown("fast");
    },function(){
        jQuery(this).find('#content1').stop().slideUp("fast");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    mainmenu();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function mainmenu(){
jQuery(".topm").hover(function(){
//alert("hai-2");
jQuery(this).find('.content').stop().slideDown("fast")
},function(){
jQuery(this).find('.content').stop().slideUp("fast");
});
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
mainmenu();
});
```

Demo : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cq9Ky/19/)